# How can I disable third-party cookies for <img> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, security, cookies

Is there a solution to disable cookies for images loaded from third-party domains using HTML5 or JavaScript techniques?

I'm looking for something similar to [`sandbox`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/iframe-embed-object.html#attr-iframe-sandbox) attribute for `<iframe>` tag, [`referrerpolicy`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#attr-img-referrerpolicy) or [`crossorigin`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#attr-img-crossorigin) attributes for `<img>` tag.

Comment: @JeremyBanks, thanks for your comments. My main idea is to show images from third-party domains, but not to allow them to set/send cookies. Treat this as a custom Twitter app.

Comment: Got it. FYI [this question was linked from a meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384864/embedding-facebook-avatars-enables-tracking-of-stack-overflow-users/387618#comment715138_387618) about how Stack Overflow itself could prevent cookies and referrers from being sent to Facebook when loading Facebook avatars on the site.

Comment: Frustratingly, there really doesn't seem to be a simple, spec-compliant, front-end-only way of doing this. Jeremy Banks notes that the accepted answer isn't guaranteed to work by spec. Using `crossorigin="anonymous"` on the image is out because it sets the request's [mode](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-mode) to "cors" and so makes the request return a network error unless an appropriate `access-control-allow-origin` header is emitted by the third-party server. Using `fetch` with `credentials: 'omit', mode: 'no-cors'` lets the request succeed but returns an "opaque" response.

Comment: The best idea I've got, which somebody could try in the next 23 hours if they want to cash in on Jeremy's bounty, is to use `fetch` followed by caching the opaque response in `CacheStorage` and then serving that opaque response as an image `src` using a service worker? I don't have time to learn how to use the tools involved in that, though.

Comment: What about using https://www.cloudimage.io/en/home? They take a URL and a size of an image and auto scale it for you. So cookies wont be a problem because that access the url? @JeremyBanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Note: This workaround does not work for:

- Firefox 68
- Safari 12.1.2

---

After several days of challenge with this issue, I can confirm this can not be done using the `<img>` tag and any currently available techniques.

The right way is to use cookieless proxy server for images like Google does, but this is too resource intensive for us at this moment.

**Acceptable workaround:**

- To disable cookie replace `<img>` with `<iframe` [`sandbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox)`>`;
- To display image inside `<iframe>` use [Data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) with inline CSS;
- To emulate `<img>` tag sizing behavior use CSS [`background-size: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) which scales the image, this allows to set width and height to the `<iframe>` which applies to the inner image;
- Use [ARIA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA) attributes to specify `role="img"` and `aria-label` as `alt` replacement.

**Example:**

```html
<img width="100" height="75" alt="About company"
     src="https://www.dtm.io/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/datamart-company.png" />

<iframe width="100" height="75" aria-label="About company" role="img"
        frameborder="0" sandbox
        src="data:text/html,<style>body{background:url('https://www.dtm.io/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/datamart-company.png') center/cover no-repeat;padding:0;margin:0;overflow:hidden}</style>"></iframe>
```

Comment: This is interesting and clever, but I'm not sure whether it works as described. I tried this in Firefox (removing the original img from the snippet first to avoid confusion), after manually setting some cookies on the domain, and they were included in the request from the iframe: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2P94.png

Comment: This does appear to work in Chrome, but reviewing the specs for sandbox, and feature policy, and any documentation I can find, I don't find any mention of sandbox affecting cookies. It may not not be a standardized behaviour that we can rely on across browsers.

Comment: @JeremyBanks, Today I retested this solution on Chrome, Opera, Firefox and Safari on macOS, Chrome and WebView on Android and Safari on iOS. Everything works fine. I use this approach for about a year in my pet-project - https://www.anonace.com

Comment: I tired a reduced example, which you can find at https://languid-barracuda.glitch.me/, and it still seems to be sending the cookies in the request in Firefox, as you can see in https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcuHC.png and the screenshot posted above. Am I doing something wrong? It doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Thats weird, I tested on Firefox 67 and 68 on macOS and it works for me: https://imgur.com/a/fQ0tgBU

Comment: It looks like the cookie *is* present in your Firefox 68 screenshot.

Comment: Yeah, something changed in Firefox 68, it released on July 9, 2019.

Comment: Posted an issue to Bugzilla - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1570980

Comment: Awesome, thanks! It'd be great if they could make this reliable.

Comment: It looks like the bug was marked private -- perhaps because it's security-related? Hoping we'll be able to see it eventually. :P

Comment: @JeremyBanks, Mozilla guys marked this issue as invalid with the following messages: "Interesting that this is a feature lots of developers seem to want. Like ReferrerPolicy, maybe this is something we should consider making into a standard." and "The standard for sandboxing doesn't say anything about suppressing cookies.". More over, after updating my Safari to 12.1.2, it also started sending cookies. Google Chrome (75, 76 and 77) still working fine. The solution with cloudimage.io proposed by Deckerz looks better to me than workarounds and "games" with browsers.

Comment: @Jeremy I am regularly polling you as network banned ex-mod. Recently I have read your 2015 nomination and I believe, you fought here with some... beast. You were banned for 5 years, and only 5 months are back. You will be the first who can get back after a network-wide ban.

Answer (score 10):

This won't be an option in most cases, but if the third-party image is being served with an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header that includes `*` or your host, it is possible to use the `crossorigin="anonymous"` attribute to disable cookies. In these cases, you should probably also include `referrerpolicy="no-referrer"` for greater privacy.

```html
<img
  src="https://graph.facebook.com/officialstackoverflow/picture"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
  referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
```

Most websites will not set this header, and you'll need to find an alternative. But some do, such as Facebook's API, and this is the simplest solution for those cases.

Comment: This was alluded to in the question and the comments, but I thought it should be written explicitly in an answer, since I was unclear about it when first reading this thread.

Comment: Shouldn't the crossorigin just taint the image, which means it's still displayed but cannot have its pixels read via canvas?

Comment: 2 years and you will be back! Be back!

Answer (score 1):

This is not an ideal solution, but you may be able to use an iframe to load the image, and then use CSS trickery to mask the iframe.

```html
<iframe class="img-frame" sandbox src="https://www.google.com/favicon.ico" />
```

Otherwise I don't know of a pure HTML way of removing the cookies.  I don't believe you can alter an iframes cookies from the parent using JavaScript, if the [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) policy from iframe prevents it.

Comment: thanks for your answer, this was one of my first approaches to solving this issue.

Comment: Best of luck, if you find the answer please leave it hear it would be interesting to know if it's possible

Comment: -1; this doesn't appear to work (at least in Chrome, it still sends cookies to Google - check your network tab at https://jsfiddle.net/mtpvuhj1), plus in a typical scenario (where you don't trust the third party, and that's the entire reason you want to disable third party cookies), it creates an unacceptable security hole. Just because a URL returns an image today doesn't mean it always will; if the third party server one day decides to instead return a HTML page containing a phishing form, then by taking this approach you'll have embedded that form into your page for them, which is very bad.

Answer (score -3):

I cannot really confirm that the code below does what you wish (because I have so much tracking protection stuff in my browsers, on my machine and on my network...) But just to add another option: Have you already tried to load the images via JavaScript?

```
<html>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      var eArr = document.getElementsByTagName('img'), e;
      for (e of eArr) {
        if (e.hasAttribute('data-src')) {
          e.src = e.getAttribute('data-src');
        }
      }
    });
  </script>

  <body>
    <img src="" data-src="https://www.google.com/favicon.ico" alt="">
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's a reasonable suggestion, but the code snippet doesn't actually use Ajax like you suggested...

Comment: Is the `script` tag allowed to be outside the `head` or `body` tag? Does it [validate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3C_Markup_Validation_Service)? If it is allowed, can you add a reference for it?