# GIS Web site slow unless cookies are disabled for the site

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I have recently had to attempt to debug a site that is SUPER slow for returning tiles (this is a GIS web site) unless, on the client side, you disable cookies.  For example....on Chrome I can go to Settings->Privacy and Security->Cookies and other Site Data and add [*.]thissite.com to the 'Sites that can never use cookies' and the tiled images will return in 30-50 ms instead of the 200-5000+ ms when cookies are enabled.

this is an etablished site that just moved from an old IIS server on windows 2003 to a windows 2019 server,

I have logged data on the backend until i am blue in the face where the images are retrieved and sent, but that is showing that very rarely goes over about 35-45 ms.

Something is happening with cookies that I am just completely unaware of because when i set the client to not allow cookies for this site, it works fine other than a couple of things that i think depend on the cookies, but the images do not...they work whether or not the cookies are enabled except that they are like turtles when the cookies are allowed.

I changed the IIS site to 'Use URI' instead of 'Use Cookies' in the session state and this made it so that the images were lightning fast but that broke all kinds of things, mainly things inside the pages that were using paths like '../here/there/image.png' instead of 'http://example.com/over/here/there/image.png' but i think that was/is because of the inline tag that is put in the query string by iis.  Some of those paths on the server side are just built in text and sent so they dont have the inline tag and do not work.

I come from a desktop world and this is my first foray into ASP.net applications/code so sorry for my lack of understanding anything.

I have complete control over the server so i was wondering if there was some sort of setting inside of IIS where i can disable cookies for JUST the images and the rest of the site can use them?

the site itself is using js to call the image retrieval stuff in a ajax'y way i think.  again, i am new to this world, sorry.  I added this part just to cover the js angle as i saw someone edited out a js tag.

Comment: Thanks @Yogi.  I will get more information here as I work on it.  I have a day into it already and am pretty frustrated.  I did compare the 2 IIS setups and could not find any differences aside from the wide variance in age of server OS (2003 to 2019) and versions of IIS.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such setting inside IIS to individually disable cookies for images. Are your website images loaded from a third-party domain using HTML5 or JavaScript?

Comment: when the app returns the div that is the tile view, there are a couple of JS functions that generate the html by adding the img elements.  the image elements have the source of  

https:\\example.com\tilegenerator.ashx?Z=12&X=501&Y=1203&L=203

there are generally 8-15 tiles on any given display at a time.  everything happens within this single domain.

Comment: You can take a look at this thread about [how to disable third-party cookies for <img> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51549390/how-can-i-disable-third-party-cookies-for-img-tags), not sure if it will help you.